# Django admin: update inline based on other inline

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Hi,

In admin panel I have created form for adding Product. Form includes 2 inline formsets as there are some models related to Product. User can create Product, then define variations of that product which different attributes. I`ll illustrate this with example. User has a t-shirt of one brand in 3 different colors and want to add them with different prices. T-shirt is created as Product with 3 Variations.

```py
class Detail(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('Attribute')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Variant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    details = models.ManyToManyField(Detail)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

I omitted Product as it is irrelevant.

```py
class DetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Detail

class VariantInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Variant

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

    inlines = [DetailInline, VariantInline]
```

This works nicely, models are saved fine, I do have a problem with Variants inline. Variants inline display Detail objects but only ones already saved in database. In order to make life of user easier best would be to add Detail objects to Variant inline when Detail objects are created, so it would have to happen before Product is saved.

- Is there a way to manually refresh Inline with values?
- Is there a mid-save I could use to create Detail objects but not Product and get back with results?
- Should model be redesigned? (I really do not want to do this, unless I have to)
- Is there different workflow that user would need to follow to add product?

I have tried to inject entries into inline by using js but this is hackish and Django did not validate formset with fake values throwing error that wrong value had been selected.

Final thoughts that came to my mind while I was writing this question. It is possible to create js that in case if Inline form of Object is altered would pass data to custom view that would create objects and get back with results. One problem that I see (beside it does not feel right) is how to inform django that new objects were created so it won`t raise an error about non existing values.

Anyway I hope someone will understand this long question.

Comment: Are you tying Detail to Product, instead of to Variant, for any specific reason?

Comment: Yes I am. It is used to filter data by js.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to mind is [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).

It's very good at keeping lots of elements in the DOM updated at the same time, and you could easily push new values back to your custom view with Ajax calls from client-side events.

There are several frameworks that can do this, but I think that Knockout is one of the easier to read and implement of the most popular ones like Backbone, Angular, Ember, etc.

Django will typically complain about dynamically added choices, but as long as they exist server-side when the form is validated, you should *theoretically* be alright.

Comment: yes it does not complain about new object in inline. However I still have problem as my Detail needs to have reference to product. I am closer but not yet there.

Comment: Sounds like you're on your way.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to drop this idea as it took to much time already and probably would take more. Also what I came up with was rather nasty hacking than coding. But instead of leaving this here hanging I`ll post any hints for other people.

I have model with two different models as inline formsets, both of them have foreign key of main model and one of them has a foreign key of other. Idea was to create fake entries in one of inlines depending on values  entered by user. As it was represented by  it was pretty easy to do with jQuery shipped along with Django. So I did but of course Django knew that this model did not exist. Solution was to create my own form and field and override clean() method as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010668/django-admin-baseinlineformset-validation-after-post).

That led to many problems, part of them was that my models depended on each other and that clean() method of field had to be cut a little to not check for db object existence. Addition to that was lack of information about POST data during field validation stage, so clean() method of form had to be overridden as there was data that was posted. However it was unclean thus had to be extracted from POST dict and validated. At this point I decided to stop as it was more and more complex and could lead to inconsistent data. I am guessing that next step would be to Override save method of ModelAdmin as created object is not in queryset tied to formset, unless there is a place somewhere on the way where it can be done.

To summarize this I have to say that at this point I would never do it this way and go with my own change_form view for better control of data flow.

tl;dr

Create custom view change_form.