# Django admin BaseInlineFormSet validation after POST

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Looking for info how django formsets validation works, though it is more complicated than it sounds. I have a formset with values, part of these values can be inserted there by javascript (it means they do not exist in database yet).

```py
class RequireOneFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):        
        if any(self.errors):
            return

        form_count = len([f for f in self.forms if f.cleaned_data])
        if form_count < 1:
            raise ValidationError(_('At least one %(object)s is required.') %
                                  {'object':
                                   _(self.model._meta.object_name.lower())})

class VariantInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Variant
    extra = 1
    formset = RequireOneFormSet


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

    class Media:
        js = (os.path.join(STATIC_URL, 'js', 'admin_utils.js'), )

    exclude = ('slug',)
    filter_horizontal = ('category',)
    inlines = [ImageInline, DetailInline, VariantInline]
    manufacturer = ModelChoiceField(Manufacturer.objects.all())
    list_filter = ('name', 'manufacturer', 'category')
    list_display = ('name', 'manufacturer')
    search_fields = ('name',)
    save_as = True
```

Next, basing on those entries I`d like to create objects during formset validation. Django complains that there is no such object in DB when 'Save' button is clicked.

I have tried to override clean method of model, clean of ModelAdmin, save_formset of formset but with no luck as these values created by javascript are filtered out earlier in process. I am looking for info which method takes care of that, and can it be overriden?

EDIT:
Added some code, used view is a generic one from Django.

Comment: Can you post some code, please?

Comment: @limelights There you go, if you want to see anything else just ask me.

Comment: So are you adding to the formset dynamically with javascript and when you try to clean or validate the validation and cleaning removes those rows?

Comment: Yes I do. I add options to select box in formset wishing to create objects during validation but as far as I checked that data is filtered out and my question is by what? Which validation removes them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve managed to resolve it. Key was to create my own field and override clean() method there. As you can see in file django/forms/models.py in class ModelMultipleChoiceField clean() is responsible for checking send values.

```
class DetailsField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def clean(self, value):     
        (code here)

class VariantForm(ModelForm):
    details = DetailsField(queryset=Detail.objects.all(),
                           widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('details', False))

class VariantInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Variant
    extra = 1
    formset = RequireOneFormSet
    form = VariantForm
```